# for-loop optimization - needed or not?

Tags: c#, optimization, for-loop

Do I have to optimize my FOR-loops like below or the compiler will do that for me?

```
//this is slow, right?
for (int i = 0; i < menuItem.DropDownItems.Count; i++)
{
    ...
}

//this should be much faster right?
for (int i = 0, count = menuItem.DropDownItems.Count; i < count; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

PS. I bet this was already posted but I haven't found anything, sorry for a possible dup.

PPS. Sorry, I code a lot of JavaScript - where we have to think these kind of optimizations... May seem ridiculous in .net-world.

Comment: You've written the code both ways. If you want to know which is faster *run them both, measure the timing of each, and then you'll know*. No need to ask the internet to make a guess when you can get a definitive answer yourself in a few seconds.

Comment: @EricLippert I also want to know and I don't want to have to write and run the code myself, times thousands of other visitors - not to mention the unending caveats for performance testing.  It's always better to know what's happening under the hood.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, it depends on how `DropDownItems.Count` is implemented - but frankly it's *likely* to be a simple field-backed property... which would make the first code just as fast as the second, but *much* more readable.

Readability first - then measure performance and micro-optimize only where necessary.

Where possible, prefer a `foreach` loop to start with though... again, on grounds of readability.

Even if you *do* want to use a temporary variable, I would keep the `for` loop itself simple, hoising the count out to separate variable. Admittedly it means a wider scope, but it's simpler:

```
int count = menuItem.DropDownItems.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

That much is just personal preference though.

Comment: +1 for the "Readability first" comment. :)
However, a `foreach` loop wouldn't work directly here because of the cast, right? So it would incur extra casts at each iteration.

Comment: @Lambert: It's hard to tell at the moment, as we haven't seen any of the code in the loop. But if there's a cast due to the `foreach` there'd usually be a cast in the loop body with a `for` anyway.

Comment: Agree, also with this UI stuff shaving of that nanosecond is not going to light up anyones day really. This stuff is peanuts compared to the time it takes to repaint the screen. Concentrate on a responsive UI by not blocking the UI thread, that will put a smile on the users face.

Comment: @Jon: The issue with the cast is, `foreach` uses `IEnumerable`, so the cast is mandatory. However, the indexer directly accesses the list, which doesn't need a cast (assuming the list itself is strongly typed, which I haven't checked). So it could save some casts.
@gjvdkamp: I agree with you on parts of it. There's certain things that are rather insignificant (like the cast here), but I've seen some situations first-hand, very similar to here, where multiple evaluations of `Count` slow down the GUI dramatically. (I'll post some code if I find it.) It's not always all that insignificant.

Comment: @Lambert: `foreach` will use `IEnumerable<T>` when it's available of course... at which point the cast can usually be removed. The only time a cast is necessary with `foreach` but not without it is if the indexed access is strongly typed (with no internal casts) but it only implements `IEnumerable`. Even so, I'd always write the most readable code first and measure it before micro-optimizing.

Comment: @Jon: (When I said `foreach` uses `IEnumerable` I meant this specific example, not in general.) And yeah, I generally agree about the code-then-measure rule. :)

Comment: "it depends on how DropDownItems.Count is implemented" - ok, let's say it RECOUNTS every time, what would be the answer?
PS. I asked "does the compiler optimizes that?" a simple "no" would do. :)

Comment: @jitbit: No, the compiler doesn't optimize it. In that case, the first form *would* be better... but I'd be very surprised to see a collection implemented like that :)

Answer (score 0):

What's the `...` part? In any question of this sort, my first response is to ask "Does it even matter, in this case?" Performance is always relative. If that exact line of code is on the stack or at the end of it more than 10% of the time, then it's worth worrying about, and that is usually very unlikely.