# in a "for" loop, is the Terminating Condition Re-Evaluated on Each Iteration?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [for loop optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093537/for-loop-optimization)
>   [for-loop optimization - needed or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477296/for-loop-optimization-needed-or-not)

e.g.

```
  int maxloop = complicated();
   for (int i=0;i<maxloop;i++){}
```

or

```
 for (int i=0;i<complicated();i++){}
```

Is the compiler smart enough to optimize it?

what about `while`?

Comment: @CodeNaked That is Java, there is no guarantee that C# works the same way

Comment: This must not be optimised as you expect! So, yes, compiler is smart enough... to know it have to be kept as it.

Comment: @Oskar - You're right. Then it's probably this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477296/for-loop-optimization-needed-or-not

Comment: @CodeNaked true, voted to close as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the compiler is not smart enough to optimize it because it cannot guarantee that `complicated()` doesn't do anything different if it is run multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to assign the output to a variable to avoid the recalculation overhead. Compiler doesn't do this because you may have an aim in putting a method return value as the limit (i.e. you may need to recalculate the limit after each iteration). To test this, just put `Thread.Sleep(5000);` in the `compilcated()` method and you'll see the wait time.

Comment: Or just but a breakpoint in the `complicated()` method and see it happen

Comment: Oh yes, simply `Debugger.Break();`

Comment: Or a simple console app test would include a `Console.WriteLine("The complicated method wrote this line");`

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't, as `complicated` could be a method depending on other complex methods or result in different behaviour after each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler cannot optimize it because there are situations in which "complicated()" will not return the same integer every time.  Therefore, the condition is executed every time.  Your first snippet of code is must more efficient.